# Realm instance for observable query is closed by another query

Tags: android, realm

I have problems with realm my realm instances. I only use realm default instance. For each query/update operation, I get a realm instance with Realm.getDefaultInstance(), and I close it when I finish the operation.

My problem is that one of those queries is an observable query. I only close this realm instance when the subscription is finished. Meanwhile, other operations can close its realm instance. I know that realm instances are obtained from a cache, so I think that one of this operations are closing the same realm instance that I get when I create my observable query, because after some operations, my observable query stops emmiting items, and when I finish my subscription, I get an exception saying that my realm instance is already closed. Does it have sense? How can avoid that?

I think this is what is happening:

```
1. Start observable query -> Realm observable instance opened
2. Start database update 1 -> Realm query1 instance opened
3. Finish database update 1 -> Realm query1 instance closed
```

...

```
4. Start database update X -> Realm observable instace opened again <- PROBLEM
5. Finish database update X -> Realm observable instance closed
6. Finish observable query -> Realm observable instance closed again -> EXCEPTION
```

This is the code where I perform my observable query:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

return realm.where(Message.class)
        .findAll().asObservable()
        .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
        .map(realm::copyFromRealm)
        .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> realm.close());
```

Is there any way to get a brand new realm instance which is not cached so that nobody can get the reference and close it?

Comment: have you considered posting real code instead of pseudocode so that people could actually see what you are doing? :P

Comment: I can't post any code, I'm sorry. I think the problem is detailed enough though.

Comment: `I only close this realm instance when the subscription is finished.` I need to know how this is done, considering that's where you're messing something up.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question with that code. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Realm's Rx integration uses the RealmResults's RealmConfiguration to increase the Realm ref-count internally (inside the Observable), so you don't need to do such magic. You could do:

```
try(Realm realm = realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    return realm.where(Message.class)
        .findAll()
        .asObservable() // synchronous query is always loaded
        .map(realm::copyFromRealm)
}
```

And it'd work. Although I don't know for sure if it helps solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, it won't solve the main problem which is that the same realm instance is used in other part of the code when I do realm.getDefaultInstance(), and after that is closed so my observable stops emitting items.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to close an Observable like this unless you call close on Realm **twice** somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the same realm instance is being closed in other place when I get a realm instance with realm.getDefaultInstance(), as I have described in my question.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. Calling `getDefaultInstance()` increments a ref count. `close()` decrements it. So unless you call `close()` more times than expected, this cannot happen.

Comment: Okey, I will look into that to see if I'm doing something wrong, thanks you very much!